# SQL to count distinct sets, reusing rows multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

I'm trying to write a query, or set of queries to count unique sets which span multiple rows, but data in rows may need to be counted more than once.

In the following set, I want a count of the following grouped by Year

```
Number of unique SID, Year, Flag1  //2013=2, 2014=2
Number of unique SID, Year, Flag2  //2013=1, 2014=0
Number of unique SID, Year, Flag3  //2013=1, 2014=2
```

Then I want to do the same thing, grouped by year/month

```
Number of unique SID, Year, Month, Flag1  //2013-Jan=2, 2013-Feb=2, 2013-Mar=1, etc
Number of unique SID, Year, Month, Flag2  //2013-Jan=1, 2013-Feb=1, 2013-Mar=1, etc
Number of unique SID, Year, Month, Flag3, //2013-Jan=1, 2013-Feb=1, 2013-Mar=1, etc
```

Data Set

```
SID    Year     Month     Flag1     Flag2     Flag3
--------------------------------------------------
1      2013     Jan         Y         Y         Y
1      2013     Feb         Y         Y         Y
1      2013     Mar         Y         Y         Y
1      2014     Jan         Y                   Y
1      2014     Feb         Y 
2      2013     Jan         Y 
2      2013     Feb         Y  
2      2014     Jan         Y                   Y      
2      2014     Feb         Y                   Y
```

I can do this with a single query for each count, but would really like to consolidate it into one query.

My multiple counts for the year look like:

```
select count(*) from 
( select distinct SID, Year, Flag1 from Table WHERE Year = '2013' ) as 2013Flag1

select count(*) from 
( select distinct SID, Year, Flag2 from Table WHERE Year = '2013' ) as 2013Flag2

select count(*) from 
( select distinct SID, Year, Flag1 from Table WHERE Year = '2014' ) as 2014Flag1
```

etc...

And the month counts look like:

```
select count(*) from 
( select distinct SID, Year, Month, Flag1 from Table WHERE Year = '2013' and Month = 'Jan' ) as 2013JanFlag1
```

etc...

Is this easier to do with queries for each count, or can I do some type of Cartesian product I can select from?  Any ideas would be wonderful.   This is coming from an Oracle database.  I believe it's version 10g.

Comment: Try `select year, count(distinct sid) from tableName group by year`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get the logic regarding the flags but maybe ROLLUP or CUBE makes the query easier and faster.

Following statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, ROLLUP(YEAR, MONTH);

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, YEAR, MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, NULL AS MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), NULL AS YEAR, NULL AS MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3;
```

And another example for CUBE:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3, GROUPING_ID(flag1, flag2, flag3) AS flag_ID
FROM a_table
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, CUBE(flag1, flag2, flag3)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3, 0 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, NULL AS flag3, 1 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, NULL AS flag2, flag3, 2 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag3 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, NULL AS flag2, NULL AS flag3, 3 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag1 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, NULL AS flag1, flag2, flag3, 4 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag2, flag3 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, NULL AS flag1, flag2, NULL AS flag3, 5 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag2 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, NULL AS flag1, NULL AS flag2, flag3, 6 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, flag3 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, NULL AS flag1, NULL AS flag2, NULL AS flag3, 7 AS flag_id 
FROM a_table 
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
```

You can use both, ROLLUP and CUBE in one GROUP BY clause.

ROLLUP and CUBE clause documentation you find here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55331

Check also functions [GROUPING_ID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions063.htm) and [GROUPING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions062.htm). This you can use for example in `HAVING` clause to limit the output according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT G.SID, G.YEAR, G.MONTH, G.FLAG, COUNT(*)
 FROM (
 SELECT Y.YEAR, Y.SID, Y.MONTH, 1 AS FLAG
 (SELECT DISTINCT SID, YEAR FROM TABLE) AS Y
 JOIN TABLE AS F
   ON F.YEAR = Y.YEAR
  AND F.FLAG1 = 'Y'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Y.YEAR, Y.SID, Y.MONTH, 2 AS FLAG
 (SELECT DISTINCT SID, YEAR FROM TABLE) AS Y
 JOIN TABLE AS F
   ON F.YEAR = Y.YEAR
  AND F.FLAG2 = 'Y'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Y.YEAR, Y.SID, Y.MONTH, 3 AS FLAG
 (SELECT DISTINCT SID, YEAR FROM TABLE) AS Y
 JOIN TABLE AS F
   ON F.YEAR = Y.YEAR
  AND F.FLAG3 = 'Y' ) AS G
  GROUP BY G.SID, G.YEAR, G.FLAG, G.MONTH
  ORDER BY G.SID, G.YEAR, G.FLAG, G.MONTH
```